# Converting Microsoft XML file format to Excel file

Tags: windows, excel, vbscript, ms-office

I have requirement that I'm not really sure on how to go about it. I have a file Doc.xml, this is in Microsoft XML format. I need to create a VB script that will change/convert the Doc.xml to Doc.xlsx, so when the user tries to open the file it will open as an Excel file.

One of the requirements is that this script will be run from the Windows Scheduler.

Any ideas or recommendation will be really appreciated.

This is the script I created and is working, but when I try to change the SaveAs extension to ".csv" the file is not being saved correctly. I guess I need to find out what the code is for saving in CSV.

```
Dim objXLApp, objXLWb, objXLWs

Set objXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objXLApp.Visible = True

Set objXLWb = objXLApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\jmejia\Desktop\XML_F\ZOOSHR_130622.xml")

'Do nothing with File, just open it to be save agains as a new file format

objXLWb.SaveAs "C:\Users\jmejia\Desktop\XML_F\ZOOSHR_130622.xlsx", 51

objXLWb.Close (False)

Set objXLWs = Nothing
Set objXLWb = Nothing

objXLApp.Quit
Set objXLApp = Nothing
```

Comment: Did you try writing the vbscript to load the file and save is a different format. It's a 10 line script, tops. At least show us that you made some effort.

Answer (score 1):

If your file was created and exported from Excel > 2006? then it will have the tags in it such that double clicking in explorer on a windows machine with any Excel that supports xml format will automatically open it in Excel.

Your file is likely to start with something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Const xlXLSX = 51

REM 51 = xlOpenXMLWorkbook (without macro's in 2007-2013, xlsx)
REM 52 = xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled (with or without macro's in 2007-2013, xlsm)
REM 50 = xlExcel12 (Excel Binary Workbook in 2007-2013 with or without macro's, xlsb)
REM 56 = xlExcel8 (97-2003 format in Excel 2007-2013, xls)

dim args
dim file
dim sFile
set args=wscript.arguments

dim wshell
Set wshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open( wshell.CurrentDirectory&"\"&args(0))

objExcel.DisplayAlerts = FALSE

objExcel.Visible = FALSE

objWorkbook.SaveAs wshell.CurrentDirectory&"\"&args(1), xlXLSX

objExcel.Quit

Wscript.Quit
```